# How much revenue do governments generate from fines, penalties, etc.?

Tags: government, comparative-politics, data-sources, fines

Recently, I got a fine from the Dutch government for forgetting to pay my taxes on time. I wonder how much revenue governments generate through fines of various sorts, like speeding tickets or administrative penalties.

Are there any in-depth (academic) resources on this topic? Have any comparisons been made between different states* on the revenue they gather through fines?

(*) By states, I meant *nation-states* in this case. But comparisons among US states also interest me

Comment: Please don't use comments to answer the question. If you would like to answer, write a real answer which lives up to our quality standards.

Comment: This is going to depend a lot on the government and the level of government in question. Some fines go to different parts of the government based on what the fine is for.

Comment: @JoeW It is not uncommon to ask non-locale specific questions about political arrangements.  Tax/fines revenue seems very on target for this site.  Which department the fees collected go to is not all that important.  Although you might find an effect when the sheriff/police department is the principal beneficiary of them.  Which, IIRC, has also been called out as a factor for [civil forfeitures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_forfeiture_in_the_United_States).

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Sure, but that wasn't my point. The issue here is that how much funding a government is going to get from fines is going to vary a lot depending on where in the world you are. I really don't think there is a one size fits all answer for this as you can likely point to examples showing almost no funding from that as well as examples showing the majority of funding from that. The level of funding from fines could also depend on how corrupt the government in question is.

Comment: Who said anything about one size fits all?  This is one data point:  the US has a large amount of municipalities where revenue is significantly from fines.  Other countries may vary and, at least for cities, it largely depends on how much autonomy local authorities have on determining fines and penalties.

Answer (score 3):

This is **not** an in-depth analysis and it only concerns the USA.  There was a comment posted before that pointed to findings in the US that would have been a good start.

However, in the wake of the [Ferguson riots/unrest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferguson_unrest), the fact emerged that the municipality had a deliberate policy of [aggressively seeking revenue](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/sep/09/ferguson-to-cap-court-fine-revenue) (in the 21% of budget range) by stringent enforcement of traffic laws.  Perhaps not entirely coincidentally the people most ticketed were poor and Black.

> According to its annual budget the city expects to collect $2.7m in court fines this year, which is more than 21% of its $12.5m annual “general revenues” and second only to sales taxes as the biggest component.
>
> The budget states that “due to a more concentrated focus on traffic enforcement, municipal court revenues have risen about 44% or $623,000” since 2010-11.

A more [comprehensive, if unclear, list of municipalities by state with large fine revenues](https://www.governing.com/archive/local-governments-high-fine-revenues-by-state.html) dating from 2017 data (not sure what the numbers refer to - number of municipalities?  but then out of how many?).  An excerpt of the first table (see comments on problems quoting the link) showing up to Louisiana which seems to be most "problematic":

[image]

The second table, *Fines per Adult Resident*, shows a not-insignificant number of cases (again, out of how many municipalities?) where fines amount to more than $500 per person.

**So it would appear that, at least for *some* US municipalities, fines can be a significant portion of their budget *and this is clustered by state*.**

In Canada, the penalties for late tax payments, *when evasion is not of concern*, are set at a rate which also applies when you overpaid the government (in which you get reimbursed), so there is limited deliberate pursuit of revenue there.

As regards the specifics of the question, *revenue at the nation state level*, the numbers are likely to be considerably lower in proportion.  The requirements per capita of a national budget is probably too big for fines to be a viable way to finance it.  It would be both a political liability, highly uncertain budgetarily and open to too many legal challenges as the amounts grow.

Comment: Not sure if a single data point is good to make much of a statement.

Comment: Did you miss the list?  That's a pretty clear indication that it is not a one-off issue.  It's a known problem with *some municipalities* in the US.

Comment: A list in a link? Can't you at least quote some of the text from the link? Not everyone has time to follow up on every link in a question to determine if the answer is good or not. Your answer is pretty short and adding some text from the links won't make it that much longer.

Comment: Sorry, was gonna do that, but the data is not easily quotable.  They are two big tables, sorted alphabetically by state.  I can't screenshot it, they are too big.  It also doesn't make sense to show just the top rows, that's just the states starting with `A`.  I've summed up the findings however:  *shows a not-insignificant number of cases where fines amount to more than $500 per person.*.  I can't say how significant or not those numbers are because I dont know, to take seemingly worse state, Louisiana, how many total municipalities it has.  So, no, I don't really want to "interpret" it more

Comment: How much of the total cost of enforcement (policing, traffic camera infrastructure, the court system, etc) is paid for by the municipality? My gut instinct guess (no data to back it up) was that it would be difficult for a self-funding jurisdiction to make significant direct "profit" from fines etc because of the cost of enforcing and collecting them, so I'd be curious to know whether local governments are leaning on state-funded systems to manage such a high share of revenue from fines, or whether I'm just totally mis-estimating.